# Android Kotlin Room database. Query fails when called from ViewModel. Passes from App Inspection window

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I have an app that use fragments, navigation and viewModels. I cannot call a query "getCustomerById" from my view model (CustomerViewModel.kt).
More details:
I am selecting customer from CustomerFragment which opens CustomerDetailFragment and display details about customer. I am using a common ViewModel for both fragments. Most of the things work, but I cannot get my query (getCustmoerbyID) to work from CustomerDetailsFragment. I have a compiler error.
The code looks like this.

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    val customer = customerViewModel.geCustomerById("11")
    Log.i(Constants.LOG_TAG, "Customer details fragment. ${customer.first().firstName}.  Done ** onViewCreated. **")
}
```

The error is in the log statement, for method first(). "Suspend function 'first' should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function"

Same issue with "getCustomerCount". I have spent hours or days on it, because of my lack of knowledge of Coroutines. I cannot put code from original app, so I have put a simplified app on github. The link is as follows.
https://github.com/msyusuf. The ViewModel is CustomerViewModel. The query is

`fun geCustomerById(cust_id: String) : Flow<Customer> { return repository.geCustomerById(cust_id) }`
Other classes are CustomerDao.kt, CustomerRepository.kt, CustomerFragment, CustomerDetailsFragment.kt.
[image: From AppInspection]

Comment: Code fails when called from CustomerDetailsFragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to launch a coroutine to call `suspend` function `Flow.first()`. In `Activity` or `Fragment` you can use [`lifecycleScope`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/package-summary#lifecyclescope), in ViewModel - [`viewModelScope`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#viewmodelscope) to launch a coroutine. Example:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        val customer = customerViewModel.geCustomerById("11")
        val name = customer.first()?.firstName;
        // ... use name
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer did solve compilation error, but call to customer.first().firstname causes an exception.                   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.yusuf.customerapp.Customer.getFirstName()' on a null object reference
        at com.yusuf.customerapp.ui.customer.CustomerDetailsFragment$onViewCreated$1.invokeSuspend(CustomerDetailsFragment.kt:58)

Comment: Can use a question mark '?' for nullable objects. Edited my answer. It seems customer doesn't exist by that id, or you need to revise your SQL request.

Comment: It is working now. Thank you very much. The problem is solved. Is there a way to say the problem is solved?

Comment: There is a check mark to the left of the answer, can click it to mark the topic solved.